# Mean Absolute Error(MAE) in pose estimation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

How I will calculate mean absolute error(MAE) in pose estimation? I know it is error between ground truth pose and predicted pose but how I will calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just look at the words MAE = Mean absolute Error

so take the mean value of the absolute value of the error

[image]